# Empty $_POST when posting from jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am doing some Add, Edit, and Delete for my project in school. The codes in the add module went well, in fact I've added few records. Then, here comes the Edit module, at first it was quite good, similar codes was used from the add module. But as I try and try, the post in the edit module was empty.

here's my edit codes:

```
$(".careersEdit").click(function () {
    var careersTableSelect = encodeURIComponent($("input:radio[name=careersTableSelect]:checked").val());
    if (careersTableSelect > 0) {
        $(".careersEditForm_load").show();
        $(".careersEditForm_error").hide();
        $(".careersEditForm").hide();
        var dataStringCareersEdit = 'careersTableSelect=' + careersTableSelect;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/careers/process/careersEditGet.php",
            data: dataStringCareersEdit,
            beforeSend: function(){
                alert(dataStringCareersEdit);
            },
            success: function () {
                setTimeout("", 5000);
                fetchResult();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Post Error");
            }
        });
        function fetchResult() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "admin/careers/process/careersEditGet.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $("input#careersEditPosition").val(result['position']);
                        $("input#careersEditCompany").val(result['company']);
                        $("input#careersEditLocation").val(result['location']);
                        $(".careersEditForm_load").hide();
                        $(".careersEditForm").show();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Fetch Error");
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        $(".careersEditForm").hide();
        $(".careersEditForm_load").hide();
        $(".careersEditForm_error").show();

    }
});
```

Here's the careersEditGet.php:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
error_reporting(0);
$careersTableSelect = $_POST['careersTableSelect'];
//$careersTableSelect = $careersTableSelect + 1;
//echo $careersTableSelect;
$query = "SELECT * FROM atsdatabase.admincareers WHERE refNum ='" . $careersTableSelect . "' LIMIT 0 , 30";
$runQuery = mysql_query($query);
if (!$runQuery) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_fetch_row($runQuery);
$array = array(
    'position' => "" . $result[1] . "",
    'company' => "" . $result[2] . "",
    'location' => "" . $result[3] . "",
);
echo json_encode($array);
mysql_close($connection);
```

?>

Yes, the code is ugly/wrong/crap, I'm quite new to jquery stuffs, about 3-4 days. To those that will help, please do correct me. I wanna learn this jquery ajax stuff. Gracias

Comment: `beforeSend: alert(dataStringCareersEdit),` needs to be `beforeSend: function() { alert(dataStringCareersEdit) },`

Comment: Changed the code, thanks. ;)

Comment: Do you see the alert with the data? is `dataStringCareersEdit` as expected?

Comment: What does the browser alerts?

Comment: why do you want to pass the same parameter twice

Comment: The dataStringCareersEdit shows even in the initial codes, thanks still mate. The post data in the php file when loaded is empty, that's my concern. The Add module works, but this edit module is non working.

Comment: If you create the `data` option as a string, you need to make sure that the parameter values are URI compliant `'careersTableSelect=' + encodeURIComponent(careersTableSelect)`

Comment: You also should have to make sure that js variables are properly encoded in required quotes

Comment: Thanks for the comments mates, thanks. Still, no changes in the result. Im sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the effort to answer this question, I've consulted to a friend who's a web developer, taught me how to properly use ajax in jquery. ;)

Comment: So why you don't write the answer here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try passing data in more common way:

change

```
data: dataStringCareersEdit,
```

to

```
data: { "careersTableSelect" : careersTableSelect },
```

Comment: Did this, still no changes. Thanks mate for taking time to help

Answer (score 0):

Call your `ajax` function once like,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "admin/careers/process/careersEditGet.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {careersTableSelect: careersTableSelect},
    success: function (result) {
       if (result) {
          $("input#careersEditPosition").val(result.position);// json not array
          $("input#careersEditCompany").val(result.company);// json not array
          $("input#careersEditLocation").val(result.location);// json not array
          $(".careersEditForm_load").hide();
          $(".careersEditForm").show();
       }
    },
    error: function () {
       alert("Fetch Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: oh I can only use an ajax function once in a function. This part was meant to: get radiobutton value, post the value to the php file, get the result from the php file, put the result in the respective textboxes for editing.

Comment: you can but there is no need of it to call `ajax` in another `ajax function`

Comment: I just need to get the data of the result after the success of the 1st ajax, that's the goal of my 2nd ajax. But still, thanks mate.

Comment: You don't need a 2nd ajax to get results of the first. Just output the results with the first call and retrieve them in the success callback

Answer (score -1):

You are doing something fundamentally wrong when u are posting Data from jQuery.Ajax..
The data should be an object and the key should be the name of the server side POST variable which will be used later in the PHP ...
Example :

```
data : {"server_side_vriable" : "Your_data_to_Post" }
```

......

```
var dataStringCareersEdit = 'careersTableSelect=' + careersTableSelect + "&careersTableSelect=" + careersTableSelect;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin/careers/process/careersEditGet.php",
                data: {"careersTableSelect" : dataStringCareersEdit},
                beforeSend: alert(dataStringCareersEdit),
                success: function () {
                    alert("Fetching Result");
                    setTimeout("", 3000);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "admin/careers/process/careersEditGet.php",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $("input#careersEditPosition").val(result['position']);
                                $("input#careersEditCompany").val(result['company']);
                                $("input#careersEditLocation").val(result['location']);
                                $(".careersEditForm_load").hide();
                                $(".careersEditForm").show();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Fetch Error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Post Error");
                }
            });
```

Comment: You're wrong. You can pass data like he does - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-2. Problem may be getting it on the server side, as personally I don't know how get it without a name in PHP.

Comment: You can get it without a name via file_get_contents('php://input')